# optimize pytesseract for reading text from pdf

Tags: pdf, tesseract, python-tesseract

Here is the file in question - https://drive.google.com/file/d/113CYSMRj2vri0tJcZrM9gNS_KASq20vs/view?usp=sharing

I need help getting the text from that type of pdf. Its a non text editable pdf that seems to be built with microsoft print to pdf option (I didn't make the pdf). You can tell its not editable as you can't click and highlight the text like you can with this pdf - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bANLBW8-7FWYc7Hkxmt0qxyvAk6BTRja/view?usp=sharing

Normally for text editable pdfs I would use the python code I already have (fitz and openpyxl) but fitz can't read text on pdfs where the text isn't editable in this case.

I need:

- The title of the page on the top right (Backpack, etc)

  The Product ID (NMBGXXXX, etc)

  The Size (8,-,blank,etc)

  The Price ($xxx.xx,etc)

  The Qty (qty:1,etc)

  The page number at the bottom of the screen

The picture and barcode can be excluded.

What I tried:

I tried using pytesseract but I get some random strings in the data and some of the product ids are wrong because it seems to have trouble differentiating between I and 1. (Below is an example of trying to print out the text of page 2 on the pdf)

```
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import cv2

# Path of the PDF file
pdf_path = """pdfs\pdf_NON_texteditable.pdf"""

# Convert PDF to PIL image objects
images = convert_from_path(pdf_path, dpi=600)
print(len(images))
print(dir(images[1]))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(images[1],
        config='--psm 6',
        lang='eng')
print(text)
```

The result:

```
BACKPACK
NMBGII9E NMBGII9I
Size: - \ Size: -
Price: $77.00 ETA: . ) Price: $77.00 ETA:
nae ~\ Re OPAC
[=] = = Bs
| NMBGI134A NMBG134C
iP ee Price: $96.00 eva: || / aeons Price: $96.00 ETA:
i i) a Of “3 a Ofao
NMBGZ125A
Size: -
Price: $87.00 ETA:
sat
OF
```

If you look on page 2 of https://drive.google.com/file/d/113CYSMRj2vri0tJcZrM9gNS_KASq20vs/view?usp=sharing and compare the result, you will notice it got the Product IDs wrong and some of the data isn't clean. I have some ideas on how to clean the string of data so i can get what I need.... maybe, but I am not sure how to get the product ids to be accurate.

Any ideas would be awesome and I am open to trying a different approach.